# How to view systemd / journald log for the isc dhcp service?

Tags: 18.04, systemd-journald

I wish to view the log file entries only for ISC DHCPd server service.

How do I do this with the journalctl tool?

I tried googling around for the answer, which didn't produce anything.

I tried `journalctl -u dhcpd` which didn't give me anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command was actually:

`journalctl -u isc-dhcp-server`